# How to make an input calculator for custom equation?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have the equation: ((A x B) - (C x D)) / (C - B)

I want to make a calculator that looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5T1F.png

That screenshot is something I edited from another website and adjusted it to what I want the final product to look similar too. Basically the user types in their numbers in the boxes and presses the answer button to reveal the answer. (to the right of the answer button)

I don't necessarily want someone to do this for me, because it might be difficult, but I want to learn how it is done. Like I said, I have edited a code from another website: edit: I cant post more then 2 links, but it looks very much like the screenshot.

I really don't know how else to do this and I want to learn how to make a "calculator" like this. You type in "A,B,C,D" in the boxes and it solves it for you. I have created this program in Python but I don't know how to make it turn into what I want it to look like. Here is a link to the python code I and a friend made: https://repl.it/FQJu/2

I will try and respond to comments, thanks! also please note, I am a noobie at this stuff.

Comment: How are the first and last boxes different? *Type in* and *Enter in* is the only difference, and what exactly are you trying to calculate? Seems like you're trying to calculate several things (since you're asking for the current damage output as well).

Comment: Can't you just build a gui around your python code?

Comment: Create four `<input>` fields with unique IDs like `id="a"`, etc. Add a button, and a div to show the answer. Then using JavaScript, set a click event listener on the button, to "get" those four fields by ID. Set their `value`s to variables like `var a`, etc. Then set the result of `((A * B) - (C * D)) / (C - B)` to the `innerHTML` of the answer div.

Comment: A good source to learn the basics of html + css + javascript is W3Schools. First learn how to build HTML forms. Then you will have to learn how to get data from the fields of a form. You can use that data to get the result you need. Finally you'll have to learn how to display the result inside the web page. It's quite simple to do: once you learn what you need, it will only take a couple of minutes to build a form like that. Good luck!

Comment: Right now I have this @Jon Uleis

`<table class=thisTable>
<tr>
<td>Type in your target average damage <input type=text class=box size=4 id=a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Enter the amount of battles you want to achieve it by <input type=text class=box size=4 id=b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Type in your current average damage <input type=text class=box size=4 id=c></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Enter in your target average damage <input type=text class=box size=4 id=d></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Answer button <input type=button class=button value="?" onclick=""></td>`
How do I create an input field?

Comment: God this website is so hard to use, i cant even get my points accross because there "Arent enough characters

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YIuo3LdTtG5czipzdRyo?p=preview Try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>

      function calculate(){
        var A = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var B = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var C = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var D = document.getElementById("d").value;

        var ans = ((A * B) - (C * D)) / (C - B);
        alert(ans);
      }
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type='number' id='a'/>
    <input type='number' id='b'/>
    <input type='number' id='c'/>
    <input type='number' id='d'/>
    <button onClick='calculate()'>calculate</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: and now the person stops learning and uses your code :..

Comment: @JohnnySnippit but make sure you use this as a reference and try to learn different ways to achieve such tasks in JS.

Comment: @jigar gala thanks for the forumla, im using it to help me with my coding, but i have one question. When I click the calculator button, a window pops up with the answer and I know that's because of the `alert(ans);` but is there any way to make the answer appear in text next to the button?

Comment: @JohnnySnippit use this method https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

Comment: @jigargala i don't know, i don't understand that. I want to make it so the answer will be revealed under or next to the "calculator" box instead of pop up on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have both python and Javascript as tags here. I feel this would be an easier task done with Javascript/HTML than python, especially if the goal is for this to be hosted on the internet somewhere.

I would suggest looking at a bare bones HTML layout, they are easily found and will give you the correct basic structure needed to display your text and input boxes.

Look into the concept of linking JQuery to your HTML through the head.
Make sure that your input boxes and your submit button have unique ID's so that you can easily access them with the javascript.

I would suggest adding a place for the answer to display, this also having a unique ID

You will also want to link a javascript file to the HTML, this would be your basic setup.

In the javascript file, you would try to accomplish the following:

1. First things first you will want to use JQuery to define a document ready statement.
2. Inside that document ready, you will want to attach a on("click") function to the submit button, based on its id, inside of the click, you will run the logic to get the values of the user inputs.
3. define a variable for your first input, and then using jquery select that element, and assign that value to the variable
4. repeat this for each input
5. Once you have all of your inputs in variables, you can do whatever math you need
6. At this point, you would want to select your answer display element with Jquery, and assign it the value of the answer to the math.
7. If you're feeling froggy, you could then use JQuery to select all of the user inputs and set them to a blank value so more calculations can easily be done.

Comment: Well i suggest him to use plane javascript before diving into jquery ..:)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form >
Enter your target average damage:
<input type="number" name="tad"><br>
Enter the amount of battles you want to achieve it:
<input  type="number"name="tnb"><br>
Enter your current number of battles:
<input type="number" name="cnb"><br>
Enter your current average damage:
<input type="number" name="cad"><br>

<button type="button" onclick="answer.value=(
((parseFloat(tnb.value) * parseFloat(tad.value)) - (parseFloat(cad.value) * parseFloat(cnb.value))) / (parseFloat(tnb.value) - parseFloat(cnb.value)) || '');
answer2.value=answer.value;
nb.value=tnb.value;">Solve</button><br>

answer:<output name="answer"></output><br><br>
You have to do <output name="answer2">?</output>
damage per game before you hit your <output name="nb">?</output> battles.
</form>
<output>
```

You can also remove the button and move the onclick string to the form's oninput. It will automatically show the answer.